# Does a motorcycle helmet count as a personal item on a modern large jet airline flight?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, hand-luggage, sport-equipment

Airlines allow passengers to carry a "personal item", that "fits under the seat in front of you", such as a shoulder bag, purse, laptop bag or *other small item*.

Have other travelers found airlines offering resistance to allowing a motorcycle helmet as a "personal item"?

On first look, it appears that the typical helmet is on the upper limit of under-seat space, but looks like it would fit in most/many cases.

A [more general question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65226/flying-with-motorcycling-gear) about bringing all kinds of motorcycle gear does exist, but **this** question is about whether those who *actually brought helmets on flights* had any problems getting aboard with both a helmet AND a carry-on.  In other words, would an airline gate agent stop someone who held both a typical 22" rolling carry on, plus a motorcycle helmet?

There is a [helpful question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2993/additional-cabin-handbag-on-flights) that elucidates experience on various airlines with the *carry on baggage count*, which is essentially what **this** question is about: what have travelers carrying crash helmets experienced when the helmet is a second carry-on?

Comment: In case of hassle, wear the helmet and say you are afraid of flying.